# How to query Laravel Eloquent data from the "one" side, not the "many" side?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got a simple set of models:

Client

- id
- email
- cohort_id

Cohort

- id
- title.

Each client belongs to one cohort, each cohort has many clients.

How do I get the cohort when I retrieve the client via:

```
Client::where('id', '=', 1);
```

This has really got me stumped!

Andy

Answer (score 1):

If the Eloquent relationship is defined correctly then simply put:

```
//find(1) is equalt to where('id','=',1)
$cohort = Client::find(1)->cohort;
```

This will retrive the cohort of the client.

Or If you want to include both the client and the cohort then use `with()`;

```
$clientWithCohort= Client::where('id',1)->with('cohort')->first();
```